# Swashbuckle is generating Swagger definition file without domain-type information (missing #/definition/domain-type part)

Tags: c#, swagger, swashbuckle, azure-api-apps, autorest

When I published my Azure REST API App it has strange result

1) Get method for "all" records works as expected, it is generated as follows:

```
public async Task<HttpOperationResponse<IList<DomainType>>> GetAllDomainObjectsWithOperationResponseAsync(...);
```

2) for `Get by id`, `Update`, `Delete` and `Create` methods, it is generated with `object` instead of domain object

```
async Task<HttpOperationResponse<object>> DeleteDomainObjectByIdWithOperationResponseAsync(..)
```

As a result, when I am using this Delete, Update, Create and GetById method, then service is not working. If I manually replace `object` with respective domain types it is working as expected, but after each service publish, wrong code is recreated...

I've tried some stuff from SwaggerConfig.cs (enabled `IncludeParameterNamesInOperationIdFilter` for instance), but it doesn't seem to help in this case.

Any ideas on what's causing this and how to handle that?

P.S. I've noticed some more unpleasant behavior - like generating `DateTime` as `DateTimeOffset?` and `byte` as `byte[]`, but I can live with that. What I don't want to fight on a regular basis is going through all the generated code to change `object` types to appropriate domain types - and in this case compiler can not help...

**EDIT**

According to comments from @olydis, it turns out generated swagger definition file is missing return type definitions in a form `$ref, "#/definition/domain-type"`.

In [MVA course Mastering Azure App Service](https://mva.microsoft.com/en-US/training-courses/mastering-azure-app-service-part-2-building-azure-api-apps-16830?l=cU8gepY4C_8605918563) (Module 4. Demonstration Integrating Discovery around 3:33) is visible sample of generated swagger definition file and there these type definitions are present.
What could cause Swashbuckle to not generate this information? I have a latest Swashbuckle version 5.x.x. Is there any prerequisites that domain-type must meet in order Swashbuckle to correctly generate Swagger file?

[Swagger definition file](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AlWjcswKM249g75W6rvw8isGbyZbNw)

**EDIT #2**

**Current work-around**

Manually edit generated swagger definition files, before generating REST API client

Comment: if this is an AutoRest problem I can reproduce (and help with) this problem if you post the corresponding Swagger file. Also, this sounds like your auto-generating the Swagger? Swashbuckle? Add the tag if so  ;-) maybe the problem is with Swashbuckle generating the wrong Swagger - AutoRest per se supports the things you describe up there

Comment: @olydis, hi, thanks! I have added a link to swagger definition file. And it is genereated when I publish my Azure REST API app - I have added a `Swashbuckle` nuget pack to my project, so I guess it is doing this Swagger generation stuff...  I'm new to this swagger/swashbuckle stuff, so perhaps this is something easy... For instance - GetPromotionById in REST API client is generated with object instead of a domain object. But interesting thing is - if I play with swagger in browser - then this method is working. Problem is only when I am working with generated REST API client

Comment: In the Swagger file you provided, `GetPromotionById` does indeed not have a return type definition, so AutoRest cannot invent any domain type to use there! I'm no expert on Swashbuckle, but it is clearly not generating Swagger that describes your service in sufficient detail. Also the `byte` as `byte[]` actually rings a bell, last time I encountered that issue, it was a deprecated version of Swashbuckle!

Comment: @olydis Thanks for the idea! I'll check this out later today. The interesting part that playing with swagger in browser - this method returns correct results.

Comment: @olydis it turns out I have latest Swashbuckle and Swashbuckle.Core installed (v5.5.3), just posted an issue (/question) on their github page... I hope there will be some help...

Answer (score 0):

You can give Swashbuckle hints as to how to formulate the Swagger JSON file (fwiw - some now refer to the swagger doc as an Open API doc).

This has kept me from having to re-tweak my generated code when I have to roll out new edits to my Web API

```
using Swashbuckle.Swagger.Annotations;

namespace MyCorp.WebApi.Controllers
{
  [Authorize]
  public class CrazyObjectController : ODataController
  {
    private MyDbModel db = new MyDbModel();

    [SwaggerResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, Type = typeof(CrazyObject))]
    [SwaggerResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, Description = "Invalid Request")]
    [Authorize(Roles = "AdminAccess")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post(CrazyObject crazObj)
    {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }

            db.CrazyObjects.Add(crazObj);
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();

            return Created(crazObj);
        }
  }
}
```

In the above block, the magic is implemented with the attribute line:
`[SwaggerResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, Type = typeof(CrazyObject))]` which associates this `Type` with the 201 response code..